# Error in Performance tab

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

From couple weeks I get an error while trying to use Performance tab.

After running the profiling I get error in console:

`Timeline recording was started in more than one page simultaneously. Session id mismatch:  and 46026.25.`

It looks like a lot of information is missing from the timeline.

This happens on all pages I have tried. I don't get this error on Canary version.

Any ideas what is wrong and how to fix it?

Edit:
Updated to Chrome 66 and still have the same issue. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to record multiple pages at the same time?

Comment: No, just trying to record single page.

Comment: If it's fixed in Canary then the team is unlikely to look into the bug. However, if it still persists in a couple of weeks then you can file a bug on it at https://crbug.com. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Same problem here. Using Chrome v66.0.3359.181 on macOS v10.13.4 (17E202)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to chrome 67 solved the issue. Not able to reproduce it anymore, not sure what was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue today.
Just did a Chrome update and it works fine now.
Chrome is now in 67.0.3396.62 (on Mac OS).